# How can I match email addresses in 2 dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frame both containing a column "Email." Ideally, the email addresses should match one by one, but because of typos or some other reasons, a lot of them cannot find a match in the other data frame.
How can I ignore cases in both columns, remove special symbols and then merge the email address?

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['/','/','/instr-analytics'],
          'Email': ['apple@gmail.com','bananA@gmail.com','peaR@gmail.com']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['/s','/d','/qinstr-analytics'],
          'Email': ['Apple@gmail.com','banana@gmail.com','peaR@gmail.com']})
```

How can I match the email addresses in this case?

Comment: what do you mean remove special symbols?

Comment: Remove symbols like @, _, !, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution depends on the size of two DataFrames

1. emails to lowercase
2. check is email valid
3. make cross join
4. calculate [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# email validation pattern
pattern = '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$'

def distance(a, b):
    "Calculates the Levenshtein distance between a and b."
    n, m = len(a), len(b)
    if n > m:
        # Make sure n <= m, to use O(min(n, m)) space
        a, b = b, a
        n, m = m, n

    current_row = range(n + 1)  # Keep current and previous row, not entire matrix
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        previous_row, current_row = current_row, [i] + [0] * n
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            add, delete, change = previous_row[j] + 1, current_row[j - 1] + 1, previous_row[j - 1]
            if a[j - 1] != b[i - 1]:
                change += 1
            current_row[j] = min(add, delete, change)

    return current_row[n]

def prepare_df(df):
    df["Email_lower"] = df["Email"].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
    df["is_valid"] = df["Email_lower"].apply(lambda x: 0 if re.match(pattern, x) is None else 1)
    # drop all invalid emails
    df = df[df["is_valid"] == 1]
    df["key"] = 0
    return df

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['/','/','/instr-analytics'],
          'Email': ['apple@gmail.com','bananA@gmail.com','peaR@gmail.com']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['/s','/d','/qinstr-analytics'],
          'Email': ['Apple@gmail.com','banana@gmail.com','peaR@gmail.com']})

prepared_df1 = prepare_df(df1)
prepared_df2 = prepare_df(df2)

cross_merge = prepared_df1.merge(prepared_df2, on="key", how="outer")
cross_merge["dist"] = cross_merge.apply(lambda row: distance(row["Email_lower_x"], row["Email_lower_y"]), axis=1)

cross_merge[cross_merge["dist"] < 1]
```

This will not work for large DataFrames, but you can optimize the solution

Answer (score 0):

If its just the mail addresses you could try to use `lower()` for the mail column and then `pd.merge`

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
df1["Email"]=df1["Email"].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
df2["Email"]=df2["Email"].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
df1.merge(df2, on="Email",)
```